# How do I put my data in a stacked bar graph

Tags: c#, winforms, mschart

I've searched for this in a long time now, and there are many examples on how to do things. 
I want to plot it inside a 100Stackedbar graph. I'm using MS chart in winform.
I have these series: Quality A, Quality B, Quality C, Quality D, Quality E, Quality F.
An example could be: A = 15, B=40, C=5, D=25, E=5, F=10.

How do I do this?

Thanks

EDITED:
I've found many examples on how to do it, but i'm too much of a newbie to understand it.

Comment: For it to be stacked all those must be for a single point, so X value would be like say product A and these values would show up as percentages in regions A,B,... (you will need to set the labels A,B ... explicitly i think)

Comment: I dont know what you mean? sry. But i'm kind'a new to coding, and I really need an example to know whats going on, and how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i suggest you take a look at ZedGraph.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/zedgraph.aspx

run the example at Bar Graph and insert this piece of code:

```
 myPane.BarSettings.Type = BarType.Stack;
```

Comment: you need to dl the .DLL file, add it to your project, create a zedGraph on your Form.design

Comment: I dont get it. What example do you want me to run?

Comment: go to the website --> best thing is to read whole page --> find the Title: Bar charts --> scroll dow to a yellow section, this is an example section --> copy the whole code --> paste in in your code project --> DL and add the .DLL file to your project --> create a ZedGraph in you Form.Design (drag it out of toolbox) --> run the program

Comment: if this all isnt working, dl the sample project on the top of the page and run it step by step to see what this program does

Answer (score -1):

Let me try to help you visualize this

A 100stacked graph will showcase against a single valid point with respect to the series
you will need to define a series for each A,B,C ... ,so that's 6 series

Now when you bind these values they should come up against a single Y value, say `1`[as seen in the graph](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489229.aspx) or maybe `product A` then these values would show up stacked on `Product A` and the values would be displayed as percentages

EDIT

Define a series and bind value for Product A and Quality A, similarly do for Product A and Quality B ,check once you have done this and i believe that should be the output you seek

Comment: Okay, so take a look at this.
The numbers are how many times a quality has been collected. 
A= 1000, B=2000, C=3000, D=4000, E=5000, F=6000. And the number of all the collected quality is 21000. We agree that the stacked bar graph should show how much A is out in percentages of 21000? and ofc of all of the others, but I dont know how to write it in code.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, but Im not that good of coding, so I dont know how to bind?

Comment: I know what mean, but I just don't know how to code it :) Thats why I asked the question.